# SQL Server: give every row same ID up to a designated number of rows then repeat

Tags: sql-server-2012, key, rowid

I'm looking to give every row in a query the same id/label up to a given number of rows and then repeat. For example, I currently have this:

```
Location    SubLocation             FromDate    ToDate     Terms
----------------------------------------------------------------
LocationA   SubLocationA            21/09/2015  11/12/2015  2
LocationA   SubLocationA            05/01/2016  06/05/2016  2
LocationA   SubLocationA            19/09/2016  09/12/2016  2
LocationA   SubLocationA            04/01/2017  05/05/2017  2
```

I want to return this:

```
Location    SubLocation             FromDate    ToDate     Terms count 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
LocationA   SubLocationA            21/09/2015  11/12/2015  2    A
LocationA   SubLocationA            05/01/2016  06/05/2016  2    A
LocationA   SubLocationA            19/09/2016  09/12/2016  2    B
LocationA   SubLocationA            04/01/2017  05/05/2017  2    B
```

So I want to label the row up to a maximum of the number in *terms* column. The terms number is variable (could be 1, 2, 3, 4 etc)

In reality the sets of dates are grouped together but there is no relationship in the db therefore I would like to create one. I'm guessing there is a relatively simple select statement I can use for this but I'm struggling to conjure it up.

Comment: What's your primary key?

Comment: Location ID, which the same for every location type. e.g. LocationA ID = 1000, LocationB ID = 1001 etc

Comment: @Carpeto, hi have you already solved this?, I was thinking the same, I have some initial works here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68d30/6, maybe we can work together to solve our common problem. (if its common) :)

Comment: i found that @row should start at -1 to start let it start from 1, then maybe we could just trim the decimal (make the value whole #)

Comment: i have updated the sql fiddle which you can find here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68d30/10, just thought might help somebody or anyone who might stumble with the same problem.